# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory on expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

please help me fix this error

this error occurs when i install the library in my expo project

```
 yarn add react-native-easy-markdown

<--- Last few GCs --->

[46238:0x4dae7b0]    86837 ms: Scavenge 2038.6 (2078.8) -> 2038.0 (2079.6) MB, 5.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.261, current mu = 0.252) allocation failure 
[46238:0x4dae7b0]    86847 ms: Scavenge 2039.3 (2079.6) -> 2038.7 (2084.1) MB, 5.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.261, current mu = 0.252) allocation failure 
[46238:0x4dae7b0]    86866 ms: Scavenge 2041.9 (2084.1) -> 2040.4 (2084.6) MB, 5.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.261, current mu = 0.252) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb02960 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa18149 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try to run `yarn cache clean`
- remove `node_modules` folder
- remove `.lock` files like `yarn.lock`
- now run `yarn`

Answer (score 0):

it seems you don't have enough resources on your computer [storage,RAM], check the Task manager while executing the installation command.
otherwise try to expand allowed memory allocated to nodejs runtime using this command: `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096`